# Kinect: Extracting audio and face tracking out of xed files

Tags: audio, kinect

I have a database with some .xed files recorded with a Kinect that I need for my current audio-visual speech recognizer.
First, I would like to extract the audio files out of the xed files. Is there a simple converter for this?
Also I want to get some face recognition features. I have already found an application that does this real time (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131044 and http://nsmoly.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/face-tracking-sdk-in-kinect-for-windows-1-5/). How do I use this with my previously recorded xed files?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

For extracting the audio you can use Kinect Studio to reproduce the recorded data. Since it works as a server it would be the input of your own c-sharp solution. 
Add code that you can find in AudioBasis sample, related to the extraction of audio beans. In function Reader_AudioFrameArrived you could find lines like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.audioBuffer.Length; i += BytesPerSample) {
    // Extract the 32-bit IEEE float sample from the byte array
    float audioSample = BitConverter.ToSingle(this.audioBuffer, i);
```

You can save audioSample in an List and then write it to a file.
Then, run your solution. Connect Kinect Studio and play your data. You should see the recorded data in the solution.

It is not the most efficient method but it just works.
Hope it helps you!